# CSS Curved Tabs like Google Chrome

Tags: css, material-ui, tabs

I'm using [Material UI Tabs](https://mui.com/api/tabs/) in React to implement curved tabs (imagine like ones shown in Google Chrome). The structure must be such that the parent can give a bottom border which should stretch across the entire row making this bottom-border appear on tabs as well as on some other content on right. The selected (or active) tab, however, must remove the bottom border applied on it by its parent.

**Expected Result:**
[image: Expected Result]

**Current Result:**
[image: Current Result]

The border from parent gets applied over the selected tab too, which is not what I want.
Here's the [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/curvy-tabs-using-material-ui-zf4hq6?file=/src/App.js) for my code.

**Approach Taken:**
I tried creating an `::after` pseudo-element positioned `absolute` for selected tab with higher `z-index`. This pseudo-element creates a white-colored horizontal line and patches it over the bottom border applied by parent to overlap parent's border. However, I could not make it work. There were a couple of other CSS changes I applied; none seemed to move the parent's border. Any help to correct the existing approach I'm taking or suggesting a new approach to get the desired result is appreciated.

(Please note that I want to keep using Material UI Tabs as the base.)

On a side note, could anyone help why there's also some lag when selecting a tab?

Comment: Yeah this border seems to just stay on top of everything, I can't get on top of it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can get your desired effect.  Remove the parent bottom border, add a new css selector so you can give tabs that arent .MuiSelected a bottom border, then give the someother content div a bottom border so the grey line continues for the full length of the page (the grey is a slightly different shade cause of mui, but you could specifically set it to the right color):

https://codesandbox.io/s/curvy-tabs-using-material-ui-forked-lx57sw?file=/src/App.js

subtabs

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import MuiTabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";

export const StyledSubTabs = styled(MuiTabs)`
  .MuiButtonBase-root.MuiTab-root {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;

    :hover {
      background: pink;
    }
  }

  .MuiButtonBase-root.MuiTab-root.Mui-selected {
    border-top: 3px solid gray;
    border-left: 3px solid gray;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
    border-bottom: none; /* not working */
    z-index: 10;

    :hover {
      background-color: pink;
    }
  }
//
//added this
//
  .MuiButtonBase-root.MuiTab-root {
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
    z-index: 10;

    :hover {
      background-color: pink;
    }
  }

  .MuiTabs-indicator {
    display: none;
  }
`;
```

app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import { StyledSubTabs } from "./SubTabs.styles";

const App = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const handleChange = (event, newIndex) => {
    console.log("SubTab - index", newIndex, event);
    setIndex(newIndex);
  };

  const parentStyles = {
    // remove this ---->  borderBottom: "3px solid gray",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center"
  };

  return (
    <div style={parentStyles}>
      <StyledSubTabs value={index} onChange={handleChange}>
        <Tab label="Tab 1" />
        <Tab label="Tab 2" />
        <Tab label="Tab 3" />
      </StyledSubTabs>
      <div
//added this
        style={{
          borderBottom: "3px solid gray",
          height: 45,
          flexGrow: 1
        }}
      >
        Some Other Content
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```